# How to backspace with X at the end of a line

Tags: key-bindings

In vim I often use `<S-x>` to 'backspace' in normal mode (deleting the char behind the cursor). However if I position the cursor at the end of the line, the last character on the line is not removed (because of course in Vim the cursor cannot move past the last character on the line). I know I can just use `x` normally to do this, but I want to know if I can change the behaviour of `<S-x>` so it does the correct thing depending on the context.

Comment: Use `set virtualedit=all` (or maybe `set ve=onemore`)

Comment: Not sure if I'm misunderstanding your question, but, if your cursor is on the last character of the line, how can Vim know whether you want the normal "backspace" behaviour, or the special-case "delete last character" behaviour? It's easy to change the behaviour to always do the latter, but surely that just shifts the "character that cannot be deleted with `<S-X>`" problem to the previous character on the line?

Comment: @Rich Hi, sorry for any confusion, I wasn't exactly sure how else to describe what I meant. As far as edits for clarity go, what would you suggest?

Comment: @Rich ok, I'll change it to that, I think you're right that it would read more clearly. I was thinking more of how the cursor *visually* appears to be behind the characters.

Comment: @myc3lium That depends on how you have Vim/your terminal configured. I think (based on no evidence whatsoever!) that, in normal mode, most Vim configurations will display the cursor as a rectangle that entirely covers/surrounds the character it is on (rather than as a vertical bar that lies visually between characters).

Comment: @myc3lium Anyhow, now you've changed it, I'll tidy up by deleting my comments about this (and this one, once you've had a chance to read it).

Comment: @myc3lium welcome to [vi.se]!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [@Matt suggests](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/21444/how-to-backspace-with-x-at-the-end-of-a-line?noredirect=1#comment38658_21444), possibly the best solution for you is to:

```
:set virtualedit=onemore
```

This allows you to move the cursor one character further to the right so you can use <kbd>Shift-X</kbd> to delete the last character on the line.

If you don't like this setting, then you can change the behaviour of <kbd>Shift-X</kbd> to act like an unshifted <kbd>x</kbd> when it's at the end of a line with an expression mapping that checks the position of the cursor:

```
:nnoremap <expr> X len(getline('.')) == getcurpos()[2] ? 'x' : 'X'
```

...but I don't really understand how this is better than the default behaviour: now you *can* delete the last character on the line with <kbd>Shift-X</kbd>, but you *can't* delete the penultimate character any more.